# Run the development server with create-react-app in AWS t2.micro

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop the React app through `AWS t2.micro (1GB Memory)` instance.

However, if I enter yarn start to start the development server, after a few seconds, freezes the server and forces me to abort my session to be able to access it again.

I tried `react-scripts --max-old-space-size=512 start` but it doesn't work at all.

How much minimum memory is needed to run the development server with CRA?

Wouldn't there be another good way than increasing the memory?

Comment: Am facing same challenge cos I am using the free tire. Did you find any solution without increasing the memory?